# @ElementCollection : Use the owning entity table of the collection

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, entity, jpa-2.0

I have this entity :

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "Group" )
public class Group implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable( name = "Group" )//this sends an exception
@Column( name = "places_availables" )
private List<Integer>       places = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent Hibernate from generating a new table and just adding a new column in the `Group` table. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: How is that going to work? A Group can have many places. How would you envisage these multiple associations getting stored in the group table?

Comment: In my mind I thought that this List could be stored in a single row like this : `[1,2,4,5,6,7]` but it seems that is not the case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form.

Comment: So there isn't any way. Even define the column as a blob or something else.

Comment: There probably is a way however it goes against the fundamentals of DB design. You can probably use a JPA 2 Converter to convert back and forth from String <> List

Comment: I'll dig this suggestion, convert to a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come back with a solution, I convert the List to String before saving it and I make the reverse operation when I retrieve it from the DB.

[image]